# WAS Liberty Profile JSF2 portlet

Tags: jsf-2, portlet, websphere-8, websphere-liberty, portletbridge

How can I develop JSF 2.0 portlets for WebSphere Liberty Profile? It seems they forgot to provide a portlet bridge. I tried to use com.ibm.faces20.portlet.FacesPortlet from WAS full profile, but that doesn't work. Furthermore I tried to use a few generic portlet bridges, but also had no success.

Comment: Maybe try to ask that question there - https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/docs/developing-portlet-applications-wdt-liberty-profile/

Comment: Portlet bridge is not yet available for Libery. Check same question on wasdev.net - [JSF in Portlet on WAS Liberty](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/164837/jsf-in-portlet-on-was-liberty.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Portlet bridge is not yet available for Liberty. Check same question on wasdev.net - [JSF in Portlet on WAS Liberty](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/164837/jsf-in-portlet-on-was-liberty.html)